# Download blank pdf file from async await response in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, download, redux, async-await

At the moment at me in case of a click on the button in my React project, component dispatch in action (Redux) with async-await and I wait for a response is caused. To download the file, I give this response and a name which is necessary for me in my helper by means of which I download the PDF file. But pdf file empty. In postman, the PDF file not empty, so with backend cannot be errors. Where was I mistaken?

My code lines...

```
export const request = createAction(DOWNLOAD_PDF);
export const success = createAction(DOWNLOAD_PDF_SUCCESS, ({ response, id }) => {
    fileDownload(response, `return-${id}.pdf`); //My helper
    return { payload: { data: response, id } };
});
export const failure = createAction(DOWNLOAD_PDF_FAIL);

export default ({ id }) => {
    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            dispatch(request());
            const response = await returns.getPdf({ id });
            dispatch(success({ response: response.data, id }));
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch(
                failure({
                    payload: {
                        message: 'Awwww, can not download PDF',
                        stack: error.stack,
                    },
                }),
            );
            errorLogger(error, DOWNLOAD_PDF);
        }
    };
};
```

And helper of course ->

```
export default function (data, fileName, format = 'utf-8') {
    if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
        const byteNumbers = new Array(data.length); // save file in IE or edge
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
            byteNumbers[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        const blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: format });
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
        return;
    }

    let url = `data:application/pdf;charset=${format}`;
    if (format === 'windows-1251') {
        url += `;base64,${btoa(data)}`;
    } else {
        url += `,${encodeURIComponent(data)}`;
    }
    const tempLink = document.createElement('a');
    tempLink.href = url;
    tempLink.setAttribute('download', fileName);
    tempLink.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    document.body.appendChild(tempLink);
    tempLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(tempLink);
}
```

**UPD 12/12/17**

If to insert this code into the browser console, then the normal PDF file is downloaded

```

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization-Domain", "http://");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization-Session", "");
xhr.onload = function(e) {
if (this.status == 200) {

const blob = new Blob([this.response], { type:'application/pdf' });

const link = document.createElement('a');
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

link.style = 'display: none';
link.href = url;
link.download = `${name}`;

document.body.appendChild(link);

link.click();

window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
document.body.removeChild(link);

}
};

xhr.send();
```

```

But if I insert the following code into the helper, then again blank PDF is downloaded.

```
const blob = new Blob([this.response], { type:'application/pdf' });

const link = document.createElement('a');
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

link.style = 'display: none';
link.href = url;
link.download = `${name}`;

document.body.appendChild(link);

link.click();

window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

document.body.removeChild(link);

What's wrong again?

Answer (score 2):

To start, the type option to the Blob() constructor requires a mime type, not a character set encoding: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob

Comment: Hmmm. Can you show what part of a code at me not correct and how it shall look? Many thx for answer!

Comment: Ok. I edit my `const blob`, but it did not solve a problem. At me on Mac OS blank pdf is still downloaded :(

Comment: You've used the format parameter in more than one place for different purposes. Did you also correct the use of format in the URL buildup? There are so many things that are potentially wrong in this code because you haven't read the corresponding documentation. The charCodeAt() method, for instance, returns utf-16, yet you're truncating that into a 8 bit array buffer. Have you stepped through this code with a debugger or have you only seen the pdf file in Postman?